# What are some latest popular libraries to emulate slow/busy/unexpected HTTP behavior?

Tags: automated-testing

I am reproducing conditions of heavy HTTP traffic on ruby app, which would mean occasionally sending 500 error codes (or others), or sending the response too slow.

My question is, which libraries makes this kind of work easy?

Answer (score 2):

I have accomplished similar using SOAPUI/ReadyAPI.

More or less it grants you the ability to send whatever HTTP requests you like to the server.  Make one that specifically causes you 500 errors and what ever other conditions you want.

Included in the program is a limited load testing functionality, but that can be (easily) extended using LoadUI.

All the applications I mention are made by a single company called [SmartBear](http://smartbear.com/) and they offer both pro and free editions.

A good starting point are this [tutorial](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/teststep-reference/http-request/.html) and [this one](http://www.soapui.org/http-recording/http-recording.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the "latest" and "popular" from the title, why would you care about popularity and age ?
The old and reliable Linux netem can help you with actually blocking networking traffic using different patterns.
I suppose that you can use fiddler at the replier level, or just write some code to mimic a server and randomly return errors, using Flask and Python for example this will take only a few 10's LOC.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is one of the most popular [free and open source load testing tools](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use), it is cross-platform, has GUI and provides record-and-replay functionality via [built-in proxy server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Simulating different networks is covered in [Controlling Bandwidth in JMeter to simulate different networks](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks) article, basically you need to change one property: `httpclient.socket.http.cps=0` for HTTP or `httpclient.socket.https.cps=0` for HTTPS protocol.

`cps` stands for "characters per second".

P.S. 500 HTTP Code isn't something you can "send", it is something you will receive in case of server internal error.